number of objects info lost when loading dataset by batches in Keras
I was working on implementing an R-CNN from scratch using Keras. I initially played with the Pascal VOC dataset without using batches and an information which you can retrieve is the number of objects in an image with len(data['objects']['label']) ; data being the output when you iterate one step through the dataset.
Now I was trying to get serious about my project and I used batches like so :
training_dataset = tfds.load(
    "voc/2007",
    split="train",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle_files=True,
)
for batch in training_dataset.take(1):
    for sample_img_labl in batch['objects']['label']:
        print(sample_img_labl)
        break

But the problem is that the sample_img_labl now has a fixed length of the longest case label (image with the most number of boxes in that batch) where it is filled with zeros if the example in that batch has less boxes than the most boxes image of the batch.
It also BTW causes an other loss of information because one of the labels is 0 (aeroplane) so I don't see how to retrieve the number of boxes information.
Is this a known issue? are there workarounds?
Thanks

These lines of code only make sense to you, without relevant details, nobody will be able to help you.
